# NET.Core, клиент-сервер для инвентаризации для телефонов и компьютеров

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Необходимо разработать приложение для инвентаризации для курсовой. Необходим сервер с базой данных (планируется PostgreSQL). Доступ к нему должен осуществляться с рабочих компьютеров посредством декстопного приложения по локальной сети организации, а также через мобильные устройства так же в формате приложения по рабочему wi-fi.

Какие технологии посоветуете использовать?

1. WPF + Xamarin?
2. Или MAUI для рабочих телефонов и компьютеров? Мне кажется это хорошим вариантом.

Работа через браузер не подходит. Как организовать сервер? Исключительно в формате серверного приложения, которое запросы обрабатывает (делала один раз небольшое клиент-серверное приложение для локальной сети, там был отдельный клиент и сервер).

И как посоветуете организовать работу нескольких сотрудников с сервером в проводной/беспроводной сети?

1. TCP?
2. HTTP?

Как правильно подобные задачи реализовывать?

Comment: MAUI + ASP.NET Core Web API (HTTP+JSON), а если упороться, то можно вместо HTTP+JSON использовать модный gRPC. На этот вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ, так как вариантов реализации куча, кому что нравится, тот то и делает.

Comment: Ваш вопрос офтоп. Много вопросов на которые сложно дать объективные ответы. Ответы будут основаны на мнениях, что может пораждать холивары, которым тут не место

Comment: `Работа через браузер не подходит.` причины?